# How do I prevent the clicks on specified element(s) inside a <a> tag not linking out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a piece of HTML like:

```
<a href="http://site.com">
  <span id="a">Click here to link to site.com</span>
  <span id="b">Click here not to link to site.com</span>
</a>
```

Without changing the DOM structure, just by JavaScript, how can I prevent `span#b` from linking to site.com when it's clicked?

I use jQuery in this project so it's better to implement with jQuery.

Thanks,

update:

Sorry I found the answers that `return false` or `.stopPropagation()` not working in a particular situation. So I have uploaded more details:

This is the DOM tree, sorry I have to hide some personal information:

[image: DOM Tree]

Here is the related code:

```
$('.span_wrapper').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('clicked');
  return false;
});
```

It still links to the page to href value of the outside `<a>` tag.

Update: here is a video explaining what I was trying:

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10201864154343615

Answer (score 6):

Just prevent the event from propagating/bubbling up from the `#b` element to the `<a>` element:

```
$('#b').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // any other code to react to this click here
});
```

There's also a shorthand version to achieve the same thing (if you don't have any other logic):

```
$('#b').on('click', false);
```

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> The value `false` is also allowed as a shorthand for a function that simply does `return false`.

Calling `return false` from the jQuery event handler is the equivalent of calling both `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`. The advantage to calling `e.preventDefault()` at the beginning of the function is that it will still prevent the link from being followed even if there are errors thrown executing the rest of the handler function.

NOTE: As always when working with elements you need to ensure they actually exist before attempting to do so. That either means a DOM ready handler or moving the script to the end of the HTML document, just before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: @DineshKanivu Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/29hdV/ I've added a note regarding ensuring the elements actually exist before working with them, if it's not working for you then it's likely that (or you've done something else wrong).

Comment: @ Anthony Grist http://jsfiddle.net/29hdV/1/   For your previous answer only i commented

Comment: @DineshKanivu Yes, just tested that. Seems odd, since it should be propagation, not the default behaviour, that causes the anchor to be followed. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Good Keep it up :) @ Anthony Grist

Comment: Not working, would you please take a look at my updated question?

Comment: $('#b').on('click', false);  Working Cooooooooooooooooolll...@ Aw Qirui Guo  > Check once again

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo Where's the code in relation to the HTML? If it's before the HTML for the elements you'll need a [DOM ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler to execute that code.

Comment: @DineshKanivu Not working yet. BTW, I need the click to do something so still need a function.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Thanks for the comment but I am quite sure I did this when the DOM is ready.

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo Try calling `e.preventDefault()` right at the beginning of the event handler function, then checking your browser's developer tools for JavaScript errors in the rest of the function. If an error is thrown before it reaches the `return false` line then it will follow the link.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Sorry, not working. I tried `$span_wrapper.click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    });`

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Even tried attach the event directly in the console. This means that the DOM is surely ready. Still directing me to the href target.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I have uploaded a video on that. https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10201864154343615 Please take a look (need to choose 'HD' to see the text). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

something like this would work i think

```
$("a #b").click(function(){return false});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not working, would you please take a look at my updated question?

Comment: @Aw Qirui Guo hi that works fine for me.  Must be something else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Stop propagation binding a `click`event to `span#b`

```
$('#b').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   return false;
});
```